# Balanced constraint

Tags: constrained-optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

In several optimization problems, we found what we called the balanced constraint(c^T • x = z )
For exp: C^T • 1 = 0 (C is a binary Matrix)

- Can I have an intuitive explanation about the concept and how it is balanced?

Comment: Are you asking about the origin of the word "balanced"?

Comment: Yes, the origin of the word in the context of constraint optimization